# How to Generate *.XmlSerializers.dll in Win Forms Application C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, clickonce, visual-studio-2012

I am developing a **Win Forms with C# in Visual Studio 2012 RC**. 
The Problem is my project is not creating

**example.XmlSerializers.dll**

in

***\bin\Debug** directory of my project.

This problem occur when i publish the project using **Click Once**.

### *What i have done already to get rid of this problem.*

1. In Project's properties Build Tab. i have set **Generate Serialization Assembly = ON**
2. In project's properties Publish Tab. I clicked on Application Files Button and select **example.XmlSerializers.dll = Include**

I have searched on Google but didn't find the satisfactory answer.

Please Help. I am in trouble. How can i get rid of it. I will be very very thankful.

Comment: I know you really want a response, but trying to "bump" this topic with a bunch of comments will not help.  Such behavior isn't well accepted around here.  FYI, I am just trying to help.  Give your question some time. SO some users subscribe to some of your tags so, with time, one of them may respond with a helpful answer.

Comment: OK... sorry... i was just tired in cornering this problem.

Comment: As a hack, have you tried just building one explictly as a post-build step using sgen? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you build your application, do the dll's show up in the \bin\debug folder? If do, then build the application, then open the Application Files dialog (in the Publish tab of your main project's properties). At the bottom of the screen, check "Show all files". Those dll's should show up. Set them to "Include" and "Required".

Comment: Yes... i did this... already... but the build fails... it says *.XmlSerializers.dll could not be found in debug directory.

Comment: Why do you think you need them? .NET creates them as needed, so maybe they're not required.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this link](http://drybridge.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/xmlserializersdll-file-not-uploaded-when-using-clickonce-publish/), which helped me sort out the problem.

Seems that the "Publish Now" button has a bug which doesn't include the [application_name].XMLserializers.dll. If you select the "Publish Wizard" button instead, your missing files should be included...